# what is wrong when I compile my .coffee files

Tags: compilation, coffeescript

Hi there Iam using coffeeScript for my apps now and I love it but recently I've been having a lot of trouble with compilation, Iam using it for a rails application and when I run

```
coffee -w -c public/javascripts
```

It will compile correctly the first time but when I do some changes it just turns to

```
(function() {

})();
```

Some time before everything was working as expected compiling correctly every time a made a change (0.9.1), but I tried to upgrade to version 0.9.2 using npm and I really had trouble, nothing worked, I installed the first time using sudo, I downloaded the source and used `sudo bin/cake install`

Answer (score 5):

You might be running into this (now fixed) issue:

http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/closed#issue/665

.. which would occur when using `--watch`, if your text editor first saved out a blank file before saving the actual file contents. You can update to the latest master to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be carriage return character problem. I experienced that in Netbeans IDE until I started using the CoffeeScript plugin for netbeans.